# Integer starting with 0 as parameter in Power BI

Tags: parameters, integer, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to create a parameter that will have an integer as value. The thing is that this value will sometimes start with a 0 and sometimes not. For now, when I put an integer starting with 0, it's automatically removed... Is it possible or do I have to convert it into a string ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a value to show up like `01` or `0003` rather than `1` or `3`, then, yes, it needs to be a string.